# Problem with Newtonsoft Json.NET performance in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, performance, json.net

I have an issue with Newtonsoft Json serializer performance after switching from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017. In our project we have to save a lot of serialized data and the difference between both VS versions is significant.

Visual Studio 2017

- debug mode: ~ 382ms to 437ms
- release mode: ~200ms

Visual Studio 2015

- debug mode: ~ 235ms to 293ms
- release mode: ~150ms

For performance measures I used this code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        var testObj = new SampleObject();
        NewtonJsonTest newtonJsonTest = new NewtonJsonTest();

        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            newtonJsonTest.Serialize("C:\\Projects\\TEMP_JSON\\Newton.json", testObj);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Serialize Time: {0}ms", NewtonJsonTest.stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Overall Time: {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        //TimeLabel.Content = "Serialize Time: " + NewtonJsonTest.stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms, Overall Time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms";
    }
}

public class SampleObject
{
    public string var1 = "1111111111";
    public string var2 = "2222222222";
    public string var3 = "3333333333";
    public int var4 = 123123123;
}
```

Class with serializing part:

```
public class NewtonJsonTest
{
    public static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    public bool Serialize(string location, object obj, Formatting format = Formatting.Indented)
    {
        string blockJson;

        using (FileStream stream = File.Create(location))
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            blockJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, format);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            var data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockJson);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        };

        return true;
    }
}
```

Anybody encountered similar problems?

Comment: 50ms over 10000 iterations is significant? Are you using different versions of Newtonsoft between the projects?

Comment: Are your figures the "Overall Time" or "Serialize Time" ? Overall Time also measures File I/O ... and are you using the same .Net Framework version?